# Integrating jQuery into the solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-list

I have a javascript file which I am editing the layout of a list with. Here is the code:

```
window.SFW = window.SFW || {};
window.SFW.urgentAlertsItem = {
customItemHtml: function (ctx) {


    var urgentAlertsItemHtml = "<div class='urgent'><h2 class='name'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</h2>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='note'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Note+ "</div>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='severity'><p>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Severity+ "</p></div>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='profile'> <img src='" + ctx.CurrentItem.Profile+"' /></div>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<button class ='moreDet'>More Detail</button></div>";
    return urgentAlertsItemHtml;
}
};

// anonymous self-executing function to setup JSLink templates on page load..
(function () {
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};

overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='urg'>";
overrideCtx.Templates.Item = window.SFW.urgentAlertsItem.customItemHtml;
overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();



$(document).ready(function () {

$(".severity").css("color", "blue");

});
```

I want to use jQuery to change the css, however I don't know how to link jquery into a js file.
Whats the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.writeln` at top of the js file. For example:

```
document.writeln('<script src="/_layouts/ProjectFolder/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new master page that include the reference to jquery and set it as your default masterpage.

Use Sharepoit Designer to create the new master page (you can duplicate the current and rename it) and set it as default.

How to do (using SharePoint Designer):

1. Run SharePoint Designer and open the Site Collection (remember to use a user with owner permissions on site collection)
2. On the Navigation sidebar (on the left) click the Master Pages item
3. Select the default master page (.master file); to know which is the default MP click on each of them and look in the "Set as Default" on top is disabled, if it is, it's your default MP.
4. Duplicate your default MP using copy and paste
5. Rename it
6. Open in advanced mode
7. Add your script tag to add reference to jquery
8. Save it
9. Set it as your default MP (using the "Set as Default" button on the top ribbon)

Answer (score 0):

Since [XsltListViewWebPart.JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx) supports multiple files to be specified, you could reference `jquery.js`(jQuery library) and `customtemplate.js`(custom template) using the following syntax:

```
~site/SiteAssets/jquery.js|~site/SiteAssets/customtemplate.js
```

Note: the delimiter `|` is used to specify multiple files.

Please follow [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/14/customize-the-rendering-of-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-2013-displaying-list-items-in-accordion/) to see an example.